# External list from SQL database with more than 2000 rows

Tags: external-list, business-data-catalog

I created external list in SP2013 which has more than 2000 rows but I still cannnot read it all, error is:

Database Connector limited response. The response from the database contains more than 2000 lines. The maximum number of lines that can be read by a database connector, is 2000. Restrictions may be altered through routine Set-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig.

Here is result of powershell script from [this site](http://akanoongo.blogspot.cz/2011/02/how-to-resolve-2000-items-resolution-in.html):
[image]
and here from CA:
[image]

Only when I have new view in database with only 1999 rows or create filter limit in SPD, I can see the external list in SP. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is one of the famous [limitation of BCS External list in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2013/01/01/external-list-limitations-in-sharepoint/). Moreover, exceeding the default max size is not recommended and not have any effect based on Microsoft support response.

**What can I do?**

Unfortunately, there are no OOTB workarounds rather than what you have done!

- Using Filter.
- Make sure that the maximum items less than 2000.

Meanwhile, you can pay a 3rd party tool like [​The Layer2 Business Data List Connector for SharePoint](http://www.layer2solutions.com/en/products/Pages/SharePoint-Business-Data-List-Connector.aspx)

- It can be used to connect almost any external data source to native SharePoint lists, e.g. SQL, ERP/CRM, OData etc.
- It is made for large scale external data integration scenarios as well and can manage more than 200.000 external items without any issues.

Comment: 3rd party tool I cannot buy, so 1999 items must be OK. Thanks for explanation.